# Date difference returning wrong answer

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datepicker

I would really like some guidance on this problem i have been facing.
I am trying to find out the difference between 2 dates from textbox.

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = TextBox1.Text.ToString().Trim();
    b = TextBox2.Text.ToString().Trim();
    DateTime c = new DateTime();
    DateTime d = new DateTime();
    c = Convert.ToDateTime(a);
    d = Convert.ToDateTime(b);
    System.TimeSpan diffr = d - c;
    Response.Write(diffr.Days);
}
```

The above is the code i have written on Button Click event.
The problem is that, the code returns the difference wrong.

i.e if the diff between 12/02/2013 and 11/02/2013 is to be found, instead of returning 1
the code returns 30.
Similarly diff between 12/02/2013 and 10/02/2013 is to be found, instead of returning 2
the code returns 61.

I am using the Jquery DatePicker for selecting the date!
Kindly help as all my search has not yielded any solutions.

Comment: December 2, 2013 and November 2, 2013 are 30 days apart. The formats are [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).

Comment: The date format isn't D/M/Y as you expect, it appears to be M/D/Y.

Comment: You should perhaps check which datetime format you have based on your culture.

Comment: `.Text.ToString()` - Why? `.Text` is already giving you a string. Similarly `= new DateTime();` - there's no need, you're going to assign a different value to `c` and `d` immediately.

Comment: I assume you are an Indian, probably from Kerala, try to use System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hi-IN"), If you have specific formatting requirement for India.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you! The format was wrong in my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is the **format of the date**.
As you have written it is showing the month difference rather than date difference.
Try using datetime.parseexact and specify your format

### Example:-

```
 string poop = "2005-12-14T14:35:32.1700000-07:00";
 DateTime poo = DateTime.ParseExact(poop,"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz",        
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In your case

```
 string sDate1=TextBox1.Text.ToString().Trim();
 string sDate2=TextBox1.Text.ToString().Trim();

 DateTime dt1= DateTime.ParseExact(sDate1,"MM-dd-yyyy",        
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 DateTime dt2= DateTime.ParseExact(sDate2,"MM-dd-yyyy",        
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

 System.TimeSpan diffr =dt2 - dt1;
 Response.Write(diffr.Days);
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You should convert your date format to dd/mm/yyyy before doing substraction.
So here is your final code-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string a, b;
        a = TextBox1.Text.ToString().Trim();
        b = TextBox2.Text.ToString().Trim();
        DateTime c = new DateTime();
        DateTime d = new DateTime();
        c = Convert.ToDateTime(a);
        d = Convert.ToDateTime(b);

        DateTime to_datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime from_datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(b, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                                     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        System.TimeSpan diffr = to_datetime - from_datetime;
        Response.Write(diffr.Days);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the jQuery datepicker's date format as

```
$("#txtDate.datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' });
```

In jQuery, you can parse the test to date as

```
var dateInJs = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm-dd-yy', $('#txtDate.datepicker').val());
```

Or in .NET you can parse the date in 'dd-MM-yyyy' format as

```
DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

also you can use CultureInfo in .NET like

```
DateTime Date = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hi-IN"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx):

```
DateTime startTime = '';
DateTime endTime = '';

TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract( startTime );
```

Next you can utilize `span.Seconds, span.Days`...etc

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is due to your computer date time format setting. Please change your computer date time format to dd/MM/yyyy format and try again.